Many popular proofs of Cantor's Diagonalization use an arbitrary function from $N \to R$, is there a simple specific function I can use instead?
There are numerous approachable proofs of Cantor's Diagonalization that start something like:
Let $f$ be any function from $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$,
or more often,
let $f$ be any function from $\mathbb{N} \to (0,1)$
I'm curious about using a specific function to make it more comfortable for novice readers who might already be used to specific functions with the domain $\mathbb{N}$ and codomain $\mathbb{R}$.
So can I use a function as simple as $f ={\pi}*{n}$? where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I have two questions:

Will the rest of the proof carry out essentially the same (diagonalization and not onto)? I think so.
Does a single specific function such as $f = {\pi}*{n}$ still make the proof work? If not, does an infinite family of function's like $f_i = {r_i}*{n}$ where each $r_i$ is a different real number suffice? Or do I need to go as far as arbitrary functions $\mathbb{N} \to (0,1)$?


Not following.  It should be an easy matter to persuade yourself that any particular function from $\mathbb N\to \mathbb R$ is not a bijection, the hard part is to show that there really is no bijection at all.  There's little point trying to eliminate candidates one at a time.

You can define a specific function, and apply the proof to help the novice understand what you are doing. But you cannot make a proof that says something about all functions (in this case, that all functions $\mathbb{N}\to(0,1)$ are not surjective) "work"  by using a specific function.

I'm curious about using a specific function to make it more comfortable for novice readers who might already be used to specific functions with the domain $\mathbb{N}$ and codomain $\mathbb{R}$. --- If you're really having difficulty with novice readers (whose level you did not specify, so I'll aim really low), then I recommend avoid all the mathy technical terms "function", "domain", "codomain" and simply talk about infinite (ordered) lists. (continued)

See, for example, the discussion on pp. 19-20 (about two-thirds through Chapter I) of Gamow's One Two Three...Infinity. I first read this when I was around age 12, before I knew what a function was or any algebra (indeed, it wasn't until the following year that I first saw negative numbers in school, although I had known about them since about age 11 from Asimov's Realm of Numbers, (continued)

which was in our county's public library), and Gamow's discussion was perfectly clear to me. (I later learned, probably within a year and probably from a "popular math book" from the 1950s or 1960s in the library, that Gamow had overlooked having to keep a tail of $9$'s from showing up.) I can assure you that if someone (or a book explanation) started spouting things like "function", "domain", etc., then back during that time (around 1970) I definitely would not have understood what was going on.

@DaveL.Renfro that’s a good point about keeping the topics and language at a consistent level and appropriate for the audience

I'm not sure if this is going to work. The point of Cantor's diagonalization proof is disproving the existence of a surjective function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. So you assume a function is surjective and then show that you can still generate numbers not on the list.
The argument is that no candidate function is surjective. It doesn't matter what you pick. It's the difference between saying, "This example won't work" and "No example you could come up with will work".
Picking some arbitrary choice and then disproving that arbitrary choice doesn't, unfortunately, show there doesn't exist some other function which might be surjective.

Yes thank you. I wasn't thinking about the overall proof technique, which make it clearer now.
